# Loop variable not initialized in For Loop with IntellijIDEA

Tags: java, loops, variables

I'm studying Java with Deitel and Deitel and I'm using the Intellij IDEA IDE. In one of the examples of the book, which I copied to the IDE, it writes a `for` loop with an initialization variable. When I run the compiler, it gives me an error saying that "java can't find symbol(variable) i". Even though I know that loop variables don't need initialization prior to the loop, I tried declaring it as an instance variable before the loop, and it does run, but the result is not what it is supposed to be (it results in one rectangle or one oval depending on which switch case I enter, but it is supposed to give me 10 of them through the for loop, which is obviously not being executed). The `switch` block is inside the `for` loop. Why isn't the `i` variable being initialized?

Here is the code.

```
package com.example.java;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Shapes extends JPanel
{
    private int choice;

    public Shapes(int userChoice)
    {
        choice = userChoice;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++);
        {
            switch(choice)
            {
            case 1:
                g.drawRect( 10 + i * 10, 10 + i * 10,
                        50 + i * 10, 50 + i*10);
                break;
            case 2:
                g.drawOval( 10 + i * 10, 10 + i * 10,
                        50 + i * 10, 50 + i*10);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Delete the semicolon at the end of `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++);`. Otherwise your `for` loop ends at the semicolon, and the `switch` block is outside the scope of `i`.

Comment: Thank you! I lost count of how many time I reread this and I still let something like this pass! I should´ve suspected it with the result I was getting!

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++);
> ```

Watch those semicolons ;)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your `for loop`:

> `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++);
>   {`

You should change it to:

`for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){`

What you were doing is executing nothing over and over again and then opening a new block.

`For loops`**`for(;;){}`** do not have the same syntax as `do while loops`**`do{}while();`**

The only case in which you can use `for(;;);` is when you want to execute a one line segment of code.

For example: `for(int index = 0; index < 5; index++)System.out.println(index);`

Answer (score 0):

`for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++);` contains a semicolon that limits the scope of the for loop to this line only. If you correct this, your code should work correctly.